# why the space $I^{(2^C)}$ is not separable

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

*I* have the space $I^{(2^{\mathfrak{c}})}$
where $I= [0,1]$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ is $| \mathbb R |$.

*M*y *professor* wrote in the lecture that the space is not *separable* and *I* would like to know why *not*.

*C*an you explain it to me?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Or Vardi: I edited, made some assumptions, let me know or roll-back if it does not work.

Comment: now its edited.

Comment: What's the topology on $(I^2)^{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: I've highlighted correct spellings of words you and/or "gary" mispelled.  I've also capitalized the first word of every sentence, and capitalized the pronoun "I",   etc.

Comment: the topology is the standart for R ( and for [0,1] )

Comment: I suppose it should be $I^{(2^C)}$, and not $(I^2)^C$. Can you confirm or deny? [The former is not separable, since the product contains too many factors, the latter is separable.]

Comment: yes i ment the first one, just had a problem writing it

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I believe they mean the product topology.

Comment: A converse to this is the case $ k=\aleph_0$ of the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem: For an infinite cardinal $k$, if $\{S_j:j\in J\} $ is a family of spaces with $ |J|\leq 2^k$ and such that the density $d(S_j)\leq k$ for every $j\in J$ , then the density of the Tychonoff product $\prod_{j\in J}S_j$ is at most $k.$

Answer (score 1):

Cardinal functions $d$ and $w$ can help here:

Let $d(X)$ (the density of $X$) be the smallest infinite cardinality of a dense subset of $X$. (well-defined as cardinal numbers are well-ordered and $|X|$ is an upperbound.)

So $X$ separable iff $d(X) = \aleph_0$.

Let $w(X)$ (the weight of $X$) be the smallest infinite cardinality of an open base for $X$. (again well-defined as $|\mathcal{T}|$ is an upper bound.)

> Lemma 1: In a regular space $X$ we have $w(X) \le 2^{d(X)}$.

Proof: fix a dense subset $D$ of size $d(X)$ and let $\mathcal{B}$ be any open base of $X$. Then the map $f: \mathcal{B} \to \mathscr{P}(D)$ defined by
$f(O) = O \cap D \,(\subseteq D)$ is an injection for regular spaces.
Hence $$w(X) \le |\mathcal{B}| \le |\mathscr{P}(D)| = 2^{d(X)}$$

> Lemma 2: for $X$ a $T_0$ space: $|X| \le 2^{w(X)}$.

Proof: let $\mathcal{B}$ be an open base for $X$. Then the map $f: X \to \mathscr{P}(\mathcal{B})$ defined by $f(x) = \{O \in \mathcal{B}: x \in O\}$
is 1-1 (for $T_0$ spaces) and so $|X| \le |\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{B})| = 2^{w(X)}$.

A consequence of the previous two lemmas for the interesting case $d(X) = \aleph_0$:

> A separable $T_3$ space $X$ can have size at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}  =2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

As $$|I^{2^\mathfrak{c}}| = \mathfrak{c}^{2^\mathfrak{c}} \ge 2^{2^{\mathfrak{c}}} > 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$$ (last step by Cantor's theorem; $\ge$ can really be $=$) this means your space cannot be separable: it's simply to big for it.

Comment: BTW there actually are separable spaces of size $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$, see my long and technical answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231320/4280) where I construct some from ultrafilters (and large products)

Comment: There are separable spaces of size $2^\mathfrak c$ because there are separable spaces of size $2$ and any product of $\mathfrak c$ separable spaces is separable.

Comment: @bof, this is in the link I gave. It's actually not quite trivial to see.