# First countable vs. second countable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be  a continous,surjective map.

Then which of the following are true -

$1)$ if $X$ is $2nd$ countable then $Y$ is $2nd$ countable.

$2)$ if $X$ is first countable then $Y$ is first countable.

$3)$if $X$ is $2nd$ countable then $Y$ is first countable.

$4)$if $X$ is First  countable then $Y$ is $2nd$ countable.

My attempts  :  i  know  that every 2nd countable  is first  countable   but every first  countable need not be  2nd countable

here  im confused that   how  can  i solved  this

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (lots of) examples of countable spaces $Y$ that are neither first- nor second-countable. Pick your favourite and fix it for now.

(Besides [Arens-Fort space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000023) and [the maximal compact topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000097), I gave constructions and proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231320/4280), e.g. use $D(\omega)$ defined there or $(\omega, \mathcal{F}\cup\{\emptyset\})$ or $X(\mathcal{F})$ for $\mathcal{F}$ a free ultrafilter on $\omega$), which all have weight $\mathfrak{c}$)

Then let $X$ be the space with the set of $Y$ but in the discrete topology. $X$ is thus both second- and first-countable (singletons form a (local) base). Let $f$ be the identity, which is continuous as all maps from a discrete space are, and a surjection.

This is a counterexample to 1,2, 3 and 4. So all are false.

Comment: thanks a lots henno sir