# Every Tychonoff space $X$ has a compactification $(Y,c)$ such that the weight of $X$ is the same of $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference from "General Topology" by Ryszard Engelking

[image: s]

First of all I ask a proof of the statement and then I ask if *every Tychonoff space $X$ have a Hausdorff compactification $(Y,c)$ such the weight of $X$ is the same of $Y$*.

As reference I say that the weight $w(X)$ of a topological space $X$ is the following quantity:

$$
w(X)=\min\{|\mathcal{B}|:\mathcal{B}\text{ is a base for } X \} + \aleph_0
$$

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You should give some more context. What is the weight of a space?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Ursyohn embedding theorem, if $\kappa=w(X)$, we can embed $X$ into $[0,1]^\kappa$ (in the product topology) via some embedding $e: X \to [0,1]^\kappa$, this uses that $X$ is a Tychonoff space.

Then $Y=\overline{e[X]}$ and $c =e$ is the required compactification, as all subspaces of $[0,1]^\kappa$ have weight $\le \kappa$ and $Y$ is compact Hausdorff as a closed subspace of the compact (Tychonoff!) Hausdorff cube $[0,1]^\kappa$.

Comment: Okay, but why $w(Y)\le k:=w(X)$?

Comment: $w(X) = w(e[X]) \le w(Y)$ as $e[X] \subseteq Y$ and so $\kappa  =w(X) \le w(Y) \le \kappa$ hence equality.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well: I don't understand why if $Y\subseteq[0,1]^k$ then $w(Y)\le k$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Because $w([0,1]^\kappa)=\kappa$ for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, and subspaces have weight $\le \kappa$ because of that.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I didn't know it; so how to prove it?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro earlier theorem in Engelking. You're quoting from the middle of his text...

Comment: Okay, so I am looking in Engelking.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I give the essential argument for another cube $D(\kappa)^\kappa$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231320/4280) as well.

Comment: To the proposer: If $B$ is a base for $X$ with $|B|\le k,$ and if $Y\subset X$ then $B'= \{b\cap Y:b\in B\}$ is  base for $Y$ with $|B'|\le k.$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Naturally the compactification is $T_2$ since $[0,1]^k$ is $T_2$ and so too $Y$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yep.