# Example of a topological space that has countably (but not finitely) many elements, is regular, but not 2nd countable

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

I'm trying to find an example of a topological space that has countably (but not finitely) many elements, is regular, but not 2nd countable.
It seems to me that if a space has countably many elements, it should have a countable basis, right? My reasoning is that every topology is a subset of the discrete topology, and the discrete topology on a countable set has a countable basis, so every topology *should* have a countable basis? This is less of an argument and more of an intuition.

Comment: It's a reasonable intuition to have but sadly it is wrong.  A coarser topology can require a larger basis.

Comment: Adding to @EricWofsey's comment, we get lucky in the case of the discrete topology. But as he said, for other topologies this need not be the case. In general, the basis for a topology is a subset of the power set, which need not be countable.

Comment: To push back against the intuition you mention, consider the topology $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{N}$ whose *(nonempty)* open sets are exactly those sets which have asymptotic density $1$; that is, $U\in\alpha$ iff *($U=\emptyset$ or)* we have $$\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\vert U\cap\{1,...,n\}\vert\over n}=1.$$ This is indeed a topology *(exercise)* and given any countable $\mathfrak{X}\subseteq\alpha$ we can find a $U\in\alpha$ which doesn't contain any element of $\mathfrak{X}$ *(exercise)*; so we have a countable non-second-countable topology! *(Unfortunately this $\alpha$ is not regular ...)*

Answer (score 1):

Define a topology $\tau$ on the set $\mathbb N$ of positive integers so that a set $U\subseteq\mathbb N$ is open iff
$$\text{either }1\notin U\text{ or else }\sum_{n\in\mathbb N\setminus U}\frac1n\lt\infty.$$

The space $(\mathbb N,\tau)$ is a countably infinite $T_4$ space but is not first countable.

Answer (score 1):

A countable dense subset of $[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ (which exists) is

- countable, and hereditarily normal Tychonoff.
- has no isolated points.
- the minimal size for a base for its topology is continuum, i.e. $|\Bbb R|$.

This is a strong counterexample. For a proof of the last fact and the existence (the others are obvious) see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231320/4280).