# Countable but not First Countable Space

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

I came across this question in Chapter 5 of [Biglist](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/biglist.pdf). I have no idea how to grab a handle on the question.

> Construct a Topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ which is countable
> (i.e., $X$ is countable) but not First countable.

I cannot conceive of any topological space which is countable but not first countable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the one-point compactification of the rationals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of a topological space that has countably (but not finitely) many elements, is regular, but not 2nd countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4295153/example-of-a-topological-space-that-has-countably-but-not-finitely-many-elemen) Note that "first countable" and "second countable" are equivalent for spaces with countably many points.

Comment: A few examples: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Countable%2B~Second%20Countable